# session.save does not return the persisted object, only the identifier

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to do this :

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public MyObject create(ObjectBasicDTO dto) {
    MyObject myObject = new MyObject (dto);
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(object);
    }
```

But I have to do this :

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = Exception.class)
    public MyObject create(ObjectBasicDTO dto) {
    MyObject myObject = new MyObject (dto);
    Long id = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(object);
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(MyObject.class, id);
    }
```

Is that right ? Thats seems lame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do `return myObject` instead. Hibernate associates the identifier to the object given as parameter to `save` .

Comment: but will `myObject` have all values or just identifier

Comment: @Nandkumar yes, it will have all the fields as it was passed to save, and the id that it's set by hibernate.

Comment: is  id  all so  return with  myObject  ?

Comment: How about other fields like timestamps(created, updated) which might get assigned when object gets persisted at DB level.. in that case , doing what Nim is initially doing seems right...given that there's no hibernate api...

Comment: what if you have update-able false to some fields and after persisting the object you want to have the properties store in the db. How can you retrieve those?